# Min/max of arbitrary type T in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, max, minimum

Is there a way to assign a variable of arbitrary type `T` it's minimum or maximum value?

```
template <typename T>
void setMax(T& var){
var=MAXIMUM_OF_TYPE_T; //can this be done?
}

T toBeMaxed;
setMax(toBeMaxed);
```

In case that `T` was `int`, I could as well do

```
var=std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

instead.

Comment: What is the maximum of `std::string`? Of any container? Or of a database connection? Of a mutex?

Comment: A string with maximum length.The content is irrelevant.

Comment: @user1459339 The point is, who defines the max of something? You'd have to specialize the template for each type

Comment: Say the maximum length is 5, is `"aaaaa"` or `"bbbbb"` the maximum string now?

Comment: The return type of string::length() is unsigned int. Every string where s.length=std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() would be maximum string.But I see your point - there could be other ways to compare strings than length, right? Anyway, I am only dealing with types like int or float. I should probably use the template specialisation then...

Comment: Can't you just define `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` for your type `T`?

Comment: You made my night with a maximum string :-))) Not to mention that traits for min/max are mostly compile-time expressions whereas string length is mostly dynamic

Comment: What's the maximum of my `enum Colour`, or of `std::fstream`? Or of my Java friend's `Object` class?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Max of your enum is sizeof of its underlying type multiplied by number of elements. Max of fstream is size of file. Not sure about Java object though. LMAO

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Sorry, the underlying of my enum is 64 bits wide and it has 12 elements, so 12 times the max is too large to fit any type. The `fstream` is on a diskless system where the only I/O is via network. The `Object` was a joke, I would of course never be friends with a Java programmer.

Comment: @Vlad: Woops, seems they're marked `constexpr` after all, my bad. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only dealing with types that have a specialization of `std::numeric_limits<T>::max();`, you can implement your function as follows:

```
#include <limits>
template <typename T>
void setMax(T& var){
    var=std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
}
int main() {
    int intvar;
    setMax(intvar);

    float floatvar;
    setMax(floatvar);

    char charvar;
    setMax(charvar);
}
```